# SQL error : column unknow whereas it does exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do this SQL query :

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    facture;

select 
    sum(lignevente0_.montant_ht) as col_4_0_
from
    ligne_vente lignevente0_,
    commande commande3_
        inner join
    client client4_ ON commande3_.client_id = client4_.id
        inner join
    stock stock5_ ON lignevente0_.stock_id = stock5_.id
        cross join
    facture facture1_,
    commande commande2_
        cross join
    lot lot7_
        cross join
    produit produit8_
        cross join
    fournisseur fournisseu11_
where
        lignevente0_.commande_id = commande3_.id
        and facture1_.commande_id = commande2_.id
        and stock5_.lot_id = lot7_.id
        and lot7_.produit_id = produit8_.id
        and lot7_.fournisseur_id = fournisseu11_.id
        and lignevente0_.commande_id = facture1_.commande_id
        and facture1_.id = 1
group by facture1_.no_facture , produit8_.tva_id , fournisseu11_.type_fournisseur_id
order by facture1_.no_facture;
```

I have an execution error :

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'lignevente0_.stock_id' in 'on
>   clause'

But ligneVente does have a stock_id column.
I don't know where I am wrong here.

Comment: JOIN chains are evaluated before comma separated tables.

Comment: Solution: Switch to explicit JOIN syntax all the way!